# How to get back the "Find applications online" option?

Tags: nautilus, executable

I need to open/ run a file which doesn't open with recommended application, so when I right click on it and after that click on 'open with other applications' then below the recommended and other applications options it must also show a third option ('Find applications online' option) which searches the internet for appropriate application to open the file and offers to install the application (example Wine). This third option has been missing from my OS for past few days, because I remember it was there initially. How to reactivate or reinstall it? Please help.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: When you click on "Other Applications.." a new dialog box opens. Do you have an option on the bottom left corner of the dialog box that reads "Find applications online"?

Comment: No! That "Find applications online" is exactly what I'm talking about! It's missing on mine.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the dialog box?

Comment: You must be having a keyboard. Well, press the PrintScreen key, which is usually with the group of keys that include End, Home, Scroll Lock, etc. (top of arrow keys). It'll prompt to save the screenshot. Upload that here.

Comment: @gauravs for the record, you need higher rep to add images.  Over time you'll gain that reputation with good questions and answers.  I've edited in the screenshot so it renders as an image instead of as a link, in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks so much Thomas, for the info and for putting up the image.